# Cassandra Login - AuthenticationFailed ... Unable to perform authentication: Cannot achieve consistency level LOCAL_QUORUM

Tags: cassandra

Summary: I have a 2 node cluster and if one of the nodes is down I am unable to login. I receive the error.

```
Connection error: ('Unable to connect to any servers', {'192.168.1.104:9042': AuthenticationFailed('Failed to authenticate to 192.168.1.104:9042: Error from server: code=0100 [Bad credentials] message="Unable to perform authentication: Cannot achieve consistency level LOCAL_QUORUM"')})
```

- I am using a ROLE I created (not a SUEPRUSER so the issue of SUPERUSER always using QUORUM should not apply here. From what I have read it should use LOCAL_ONE but isn't!
- I've set up **system_auth** keyspace replication to 2 on purpose as this is recommended to not have a single point of failure.

Here is a screenshot to show I am not using the cassandra SUPERUSER yet getting the error:
[image]

I would like login to continue working even if one node is down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct when you say "From what I have read it should use LOCAL_ONE but isn't!"

I found that the official [Security documentation](https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/4.1/cassandra/operating/security.html#password-authentication) for both Cassandra 4.0 and 4.1 is outdated by missing a change to authentication consistency introduced in Cassandra 4.0.

In the NEWS.txt you can find the following on Cassandra 4.0 "New Features" section:

> Authentication reads and writes have been changed from a mix of ONE, LOCAL_ONE, and QUORUM                                                                                                                                                   to LOCAL_QUORUM on reads and EACH_QUORUM on writes. This is configurable via cassandra.yaml with                                                                                                                                             auth_read_consistency_level and auth_write_consistency_level respectively. See CASSANDRA-12988.

In the Apache Cassandra documentation for cassandra.yaml you can find the default consistencies for [reads](https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/stable/cassandra/configuration/cass_yaml_file.html#auth_read_consistency_level) (LOCAL_QUORUM) and [writes](https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/stable/cassandra/configuration/cass_yaml_file.html#auth_write_consistency_level) (EACH_QUORUM) against the **system_auth** keyspace.

The good news is that you can configure the respective consistency levels, or at least **auth_read_consistency_level** to **LOCAL_ONE**, in **cassandra.yaml** (check the links for reads and writes above), restart the node(s) and then you should be able to authenticate to cqlsh.

As a side note, not all superusers log in (or used to) with QUORUM. At least up until Cassandra 4, only the "cassandra" superuser used QUORUM. All the remaining users, super or otherwise, authenticated with LOCAL_ONE. I didn't test it yet, but from the NEWS.txt update I assume that the configured consistency in the yaml also applies to the "cassandra" superuser from Cassandra 4 onwards.

Comment: Great research. and indeed adding `auth_read_consistency_level: LOCAL_ONE` lets me log in even if one of the two nodes is down. As I wrote in my question, I saw that even new superusers I created needed LOCAL_QUORUM by default to login.

Comment: Great stumbling upon this one. This is something I assumed to be consistent between Cassandra 3 and 4. So I'm glad, thanks to you, that I discovered I was wrong about it!

Answer (score 2):

First, a 2-node cluster is not a good replication setting for a quorum level as a quorum value of RF=2 would always be (2/2)+1=2. RF=3 which each replica nodes placed in its own rack is always a preferred starting set-up, but let's park that discussion aside for now.

You could force the consistency level via the CQLSH options like below,

```
bin/cqlsh host:port --username=<user_name> --password=<password> --debug
```

and then leveraging `CONSISTENCY LOCAL_ONE;` inside the shell will get you working with that read consistency level.

I could see that [the default CQLSH consistency level is `LOCAL_ONE` here for Cassandra® `4.1.3`](https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/cassandra-4.1.3/bin/cqlsh.py#L503) unless you have it re-configured it elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, though when I use `--consistency-level LOCAL_ONE` I get "Usage: cqlsh.py [options] [host [port]]

cqlsh.py: error: no such option: --consistency-level"

Comment: gotcha, thanks for pointing that out. I mixed up versions and this version don't have that config. I'll adjust my answer above.